# Retrieve latest update time for male and female members with low selectivity?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a SQL Server and want to find out the latest update time for male and female members.  What is the most efficient way to create an index to find the data I need with such low selectivity?  Thanks for all your help.

```
SELECT sex, COUNT(1) FROM membership
```

Produces:

| sex | COUNT(1) |
| --- | --- |
| M | 887409 |
| F | 679003 |

And

```
SELECT sex, max(UpdateTime) FROM membership
```

Produces:

| sex | max(UpdateTime) |
| --- | --- |
| M | 2023-05-29 18:30:09 |
| F | 2023-05-27 12:23:55 |

Comment: What is the problem with what you've tried?

Comment: An index on `sex, UpdateTime` could allow both values to be determined by two `TOP 1` index seeks - each reading a single row. But also an index on UpdateTime could also work fine. Assuming there is no particular correlation in when `M` and `F` update their membership it could read the index on UpdateTime in descending order and stop after finding the first M and first F (if they are randomly distributed chances are it will need to read less than 10 rows to see one of each).  The SQL to get that execution plan that stops without doing the whole scan will be trickier though

Comment: I presume that `... GROUP BY sex` is required on both of the OP's queries.

Comment: I agree with @MartinSmith that an index on `(sex, UpdateTime)` *(in that order)* would yield the most efficient execution. However, I believe an index on `(UpdateTime, sex)` or `(UpdateTime) INCLUDE(sex)` would be sub-optimal because a full index scan would likely be needed to ensure that all distinct `sex` values are covered. (The engine doesn't know that there are only two values.) I don't think an index on just `(UpdateTime)` would be of much use, because it would also require a clustered index lookup to access `sex`, at which point the engine might as well just do a table scan.

Comment: @Bohemian I wonder what is the best index we can have.

Comment: @TN You are correct that this is a hard choice even for such a simple query.

Comment: @tako I don't think any index will help you much because there's not enough to filter on.

Comment: @TN yeah you would have to write a query that has knowledge that it can stop after it finds the first `M` and first `F` - but this is also the case if you just send two `TOP 1` queries and don't implement something like the recursive CTE approach to dynamically discover the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query can be supported purely by a single column index on `(sex)`. But both queries can instead be supported by the following index

```
INDEX IX NONCLUSTERED (sex ASC, UpdateTime DESC)
-- alternatively
INDEX IX CLUSTERED (sex ASC, UpdateTime DESC)
```

The second query could be improved in this case, by instead doing separate `TOP 1` queries for each value

```sql
SELECT
  m.*
FROM (VALUES
  ('M'),
  ('F')
) v(sex)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      m.sex,
      m.UpdateTime
    FROM membership m
    WHERE m.sex = v.sex
    ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC
) m;
```

If you have a column where you don't know the exact values, but wish to do a similar *skip-scanning* technique, you can use a recursive CTE and a function instead.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTopValue (@sexPrevious char(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT TOP (1)
      sex,
      UpdateTime
    FROM membership
    WHERE sex > @sex
    ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC;
```

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      sex,
      UpdateTime
    FROM membership
    ORDER BY sex ASC, UpdateTime DESC

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      t.sex,
      t.UpdateTime
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY dbo.GetTopValue(cte.sex) t
)
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```